# Amsmath: Using \tag{name} when you have a long name

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath

When the name is long, the centering of the equations is off even though the tagged name wouldn't overlap the content.  How can I center equations with a long name?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  1 &= 1\\
  2 &= 2\tag{This is a long tag}\\
  3 &= 3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

From the image below, we can see that there is enough space to center the equations with the document and not have overlap.

[image]

Comment: Is inserting `\mkern-50mu` or `\mspace{-50mu}`  after the second equation an option? You can automate it but is it an option to modify the equation set instead of tag handling?

Comment: @percusse `\mkern-50mu` moves it over but is that guess on how far to move it or is would `50` mu units be the actual amount to center?

Comment: Just a quick guess. `mu` is math unit and 1/18 of `1em`. Hence the round number.

Comment: @percusse do you know if there is a command that will figure out the correct adjustment to center?

Comment: You can measure the length of your tag and insert the required negative math space. However, amsmath parses the content twice first measures the content then typesets so it might be tricky. Use `mathtools` anyway :)

Comment: Can you explain why you need such long tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to hide the tag width using, for example, a `\makebox`; inside the `Dequation` environment, the tag width will not be taken into account:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Dequation}
  {%
  \def\tagform@##1{%
    \maketag@@@{\makebox[0pt][r]{(\ignorespaces##1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}}%
  \ignorespaces
  }
  {%
  \def\tagform@##1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces##1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
  }
\makeatother    

\begin{document}

A regular \texttt{align*} with long tags:
\begin{align*}
  1 &= 1\\
  2 &= 2\tag{This is a long tag}\\
  3 &= 3\tag{This is an even longer tag}
\end{align*}
A regular \texttt{align*} without tags, for comparison:
\begin{align*}
  1 &= 1\\
  2 &= 2\\
  3 &= 3
\end{align*}
An \texttt{align*} with long tags inside \texttt{Dequation}:
\begin{Dequation}
\begin{align*}
  1 &= 1\\
  2 &= 2\tag{This is a long tag}\\
  3 &= 3\tag{This is an even longer tag}
\end{align*}
\end{Dequation}
The initial regular \texttt{align*} with long tags, for comparison:
\begin{align*}
  1 &= 1\\
  2 &= 2\tag{This is a long tag}\\
  3 &= 3\tag{This is an even longer tag}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could add the longest tag on the opposite side as a `\phantom` in order to "restore" the horizontal shift:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  1 &= 1 \\
  2 &= 2 \\
  3 &= 3
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  1 &= 1 \\
  2 &= 2 \tag{This is a long tag} \\
  3 &= 3
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  1 &= 1 \\
  \phantom{\text{(This is a long tag)}}2 &= 2 \tag{This is a long tag} \\
  3 &= 3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```