# Equations not properly centered when using \tag in gather* environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath

Consider the following MWE: three boxes, all the same width, in a `gather*` environment. I expect that all boxes will be centered around the same vertical line. However, the length of the tags messes this up, and alignment looks pretty bad.

```
\documentclass[preview,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{gather*}
    \framebox[.7\linewidth]{} \\
    \framebox[.7\linewidth]{} \tag{short} \\
    \framebox[.7\linewidth]{} \tag{pretty long}
  \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Is this expected behaviour, or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: Make MWE compile, add output.

Comment: this might be helpful: [Amsmath: Using \tag{name} when you have a long name](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126797/579)

Comment: If you surround the `\framebox` with `\makebox[0pt]{`...`}`, it will force each box to be centered, but then it collides with the `(pretty long)` tag. I don't know if this is the answer to your question (I have absolutely no idea if this is intended behavior), though.

Comment: Thanks @barbara, @Arun for the suggestions. Indeed the zero-width label trick only works if the equations do not need to shift to fit the label. I managed to work around it by creating an `align` variant with centering columns, but I still would expect gather to behave differently.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with the `\newtagform` command from `mathtools`. Of course it's up to you to ensure equations and tags do not overlap.

```
\documentclass{article}%[preview,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{nowidth}{\llap\bgroup(}{)\egroup}

\begin{document}

\usetagform{nowidth}
  \begin{gather*}
    \framebox[.6\linewidth]{} \\
    \framebox[.6\linewidth]{} \tag{short} \\
    \framebox[.6\linewidth]{} \tag{pretty long}
  \end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]